# Extern php file showing up IF radio button true

Tags: php, file, if-statement, extern

I want to build a guide where you first choose what kind of recipe you want to create.
The next side I want to show up with the needed further questions:
If you choose drinkA then show content of subfile xyz.
But what ever I try it doesnt show me the content of the result of the radiobuttons.

```
<label>
          <input type="radio" name="type" value="tea">
          <img src="img/tea.gif"  class="image-button" alt="Tea recipe">
      </label>



<?php
    if($_POST['type'] == "coffee") {
      include ("inc/coffee.php");
   } else if($_POST['type'] == "specialityCoffee") {
      include ('inc/speciality-coffee.php');
   } else if($_POST['type'] == "coldDrip") {
      include ('inc/cold-drip.php');
   } else if($_POST['type'] == "tea") {
      include ('inc/tea.php');
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `<form>` for each iteration and adding the type="radio" to a form tag. You should create the form tag outside of the foreach loop.

I think you are looking for the input element like `<input type="radio">` and you should make sure that you don't duplicate the id's in the loop.

That could be done by using for example id="one-$val"

```
foreach ($json_var as $value) {
    if ($value["name"] === "counting animals") {
        printf('<img src="' . $value["data"] . '" />');
        printf("<form id=\"form1\">");
        foreach ($value["choices"] as $val) {
            printf("<input name=\"image-pick\" value=$val type=\"radio\" id=\"one-$val\" >" );
            printf("<label></label>");
        }
        printf("</form>");
    }
}
```